# Firefox iframe referrer is trimmed despite referrerpolicy="unsafe-url"

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, iframe, referrer-policy

I'm having an implementation of an iframe which is used on many third-party websites.
Within the iframe there is a login that redirects to my main page for login and should redirect back to the third party site then.

The iframe is having referrerpolicy="unsafe-url" so the iframe gets the full-url to redirect back to:

```
<iframe referrerpolicy="unsafe-url" ....>
```

This works all and good **except** in firefox.

In all other browsers its [www.example.com/subpage/pagewithmyiframe.html](http://www.example.com/subpage/pagewithmyiframe.html)

In firefox its only [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)
Which is a problem, why does firefox completely ignore the referrerpolicy parameter?

Is this a firefox bug? Why is there no way to control if I want to trust this url or not. thats what the referrerpolicy parameter is there for. I want to control if I allow it or not.

Answer (score 0):

I have just hit the same problem that you and it appears to be caused by a "Enhaned Tracking Protection" feature in firefox. Once you disable that, it starts sending full referrer again.

<sup>https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1720294</sup>
<sup>https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1727301</sup>